# Expectation of the minimum between a R.V. and a constant

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable with mean $\mu>0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and $C$ be a positive constant. I want to find a lower bound of the expectation of $\min(X,c)$ and hope this lower bound is only related to $\mu, \sigma^2$ and $c$. How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about finding a "lower bound" for the minimum. Usually, for order statistics, we are interested in the "upper bound" given $n$ samples. Also, as  the number of samples $n$ gets large, the expected value tends to 0 (or to whatever the minimum value of the support is). Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: I mean I want to find a number $L>0$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,c)]\geq L$, and this $L$ is a fuction of $\mu,\sigma^2,c$, i.e., $L=L(\mu,\sigma^2,c)$. I am not sure if the problem is clear to you now.